# FloatField instead of IntegerField in admin

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

I am storing data as Integers:

```
class Something(models.Model):
    value = models.IntegerField(blank = True)
```

but I would like to allow user to edit this as *FloatField* in **django admin site**, for instance - I am storing price in dollars as the number of cents, but I would like users to edit the price in ordinary way, and then do necessary math and transform floats to integers.

Is this possible, and if so, how would I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is all form-related stuff.

Read up on widgets and validation.  You can replace the data during validation, that's why the method is called `clean`.

http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/topics/forms/modelforms/#overriding-the-default-field-types-or-widgets

http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/forms/validation/#

Comment: ok, that looks fine, but how can I render integer value from model as 100 times smaller float in corresponding admin?

Comment: @Tomek: That's one reason for using http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/models/fields/#decimalfield instead of integer.

Comment: @Tomek: If you must store them completely separately, you'll need to make a custom `Form` class and give it to the admin.